# Slow server performance. Is it the hardware's fault?

Tags: performance, virtual-machines, central-processing-unit

We recently ordered a new server machine to beef up page load times of the websites we are hosting. The hardware is provided and partially managed by a hosting company. The dedicated machine has two [Intel Xeon E5-2650](https://ark.intel.com/products/64590/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2650-20M-Cache-2_00-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI), <strike>which are split into two VMs via KVM</strike>. These <strike>VMs</strike> machines are running Windows Server 2012 R2, which use HyperV for 5 additional VMs. One of these VMs is used as the web application server. The VM is set up with 4 physical cores (8 logical cores due to HT support) and has 64 GB RAM assigned to it.

We are running Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5, Tomcat 7, ColdFusion 10 (JDK 8) on it. The performance (page load times per request) is randomly peaking really bad since we moved from our old server to the new server. I monitored common bottlenecks such as thread waits on database, network, IO, GC pauses, worker- and connection numbers, but everything seems perfectly fine here (the codebase and configuration didn't change anyway). Most of the wasted time is in fact spent on the CPU, although the load rarely exceeds 60%. I then tested single units of our web applications and raw processing performance (some number crunching and memory operations) and compared the measured times with a local developer server.

The local machine is an [Intel i7 3930](https://ark.intel.com/products/63697/Intel-Core-i7-3930K-Processor-12M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz) at 4.2 GHz. **The i7 performed 5-6 times faster than the Xeon on every single task.** I am aware of the fact, that desktop CPUs tend to be faster in such a comparison, especially due to the high clockrate here - but this gap seems too extreme, no?

Now I'm am actually not even involved with the server and infrastructure (I'm just the software developer), but I can't stop thinking, that the hosting company sold us "old hardware", which underperforms for what we actually desired. Or is it related to how the VMs are nested? Or are server CPUs just that much slower in general?

I'm about to bring this topic up and blame it on the hardware. So I want to get a second opinion on this before doing so.

Comment: So you're running virtual machines under Hyper-V, which is itself a virtual machine under KVM? Why the nested virtualization? Why not just run Windows Server virtual machines hosting these websites directly under KVM?

Comment: The KVM is managed by the hosting company and it's probably related to how backups and the heartbeat failover works. I don't know exact details either. Do you expect the nesting to be critical for the performance?

Comment: My personal opinion (because I have no experience with KVM) is that a nested VM is very likely to have performance problems. You're dealing with multiple layers of hardware virtualization (instead of just one) and it's very likely that's the cause of the issue.

Comment: Nested virtualization has a _significant_ CPU performance penalty, though in my testing it's averaged around 20-25%, but varied very widely depending on workload. Whatever is going on here, you definitely should get more information from the hosting provider, or from whoever is supposed to be managing the server.

Comment: I was misinformed about KVM. The HyperV VMs are running on dedicated machines, so no VM nesting at all.